# View character encoding of file in BBEdit

Tags: bbedit

I know you can open the current opened file using another character encoding, but how do you view what character encoding, the file is currently opened with?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's right at the bottom in the status bar:

[image]

<sub>Screenshot's from TextWrangler, but I guess BBEdit's the same.</sub>

Answer (score 3):

Whilst @slhck's answer is correct the text encoding wasn't available in the status bar until I had enabled the option in Preferences...

[image]